# Why am I getting a syntax error with my php session?

Tags: php

I am trying to make the page not load if the user isn't logged in.

```
<?php    
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) {
    die("You must be logged in.");
}
?>
```

With this code, it is giving me an unexpected '{' on line 3 (line starting with if). I have tried changing it, but it still gives me the error.

Comment: You're missing a `)` in your if

Comment: Count the opening and closing parenthesis.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too-localised.

Answer (score 2):

There's a missing parenthesis at the end of the IF condition:

```
// ------------------------------v
if (!isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])) {
    die("You must be logged in.");
}
```